# How to change hostname

Tags: 12.04, configuration, hostname, hosts, etc

I have updated my system's hostname in `/etc/hostname` file as master. I have also mapped my `/etc/hosts` file like

```
<ip> master
```

Still, when I type `$ hostname`, I get a different hostname.

I basically want to change my hostname from the default one to "master".

What file am I missing out?

Comment: What is `<ip>` the placeholder for? It should be 127.0.1.1

Comment: Your host name is by default your machine name. If you have Apache installed, it can be typed into the url bar. So mine is Hairy14, and I see my locally hosted website. Why do you need to change it?

Comment: I am working on hadoop with ec2 instances. I would want to change my instance names to master and slaves for easy tracking while working on the terminal

Comment: Just use localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The problem is that you should have:</s>

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   master
```

in your `/etch/hosts` file, not a real `ip` address.

Simply run the command `sudo hostname your-new-name`

If that doesn't work, can you not use localhost instead of master?

Comment: I changed my host file as you said and reconnected to the instance. Still when I type $hostname, I get "ip-<ip address>" which was my default hostname.